# SAP HCI: get more entities than page size

Tags: hana, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

I don't actually know if this is the right place to ask and don't even know if I can phrase my question correctly, but I'll try:

My employer starts using SuccessFactors by SAP soon and I try to design some very basic HANA Cloud Integration Flows. I am really just a "end user" in this case, no insight to the technical background/implementation at all.

It seems to work all fine, despite in one case when I'd need to retrieve more result entities than the "page size". I heard that the page size cannot be very high, so I tried to go with 800 for now. But there are more entries. So from what I read, I need to use a looping process call together with "Process in Batches" feature in the Receiver Channel... This is my current iflow:

[image: PerPerson iflow]

But still only the first 800 entities are returned. Do you see something obviously wrong here, or any idea where to find comprehensive documentation about this feature, because Google didn't give me much...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SuccessFactors adapter in V2/V4 mode works well for any page size.
You don't actually need use only looping process therefore V2/V4 supports non-iterable output.

So, you could make simplest IFlow: 
Https sender -> Start -> Content modifier -> Request/Reply -> XML to Json -> End

On SFSF adapter, clear "Process in Pages" checkbox.

Comment: otherwise provide some more information on your adapter configuration to retrieva the data... think is not a big thing to solve it.